# How to get the Values in between the Square Brackets in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a string 
`[34567].[56].[1]`

I need the output as

```
Column A column B column C
34567     56        1
```

```sql
select REGEXP_REPLACE('[34533].[54].[1]' , '[^0-9.\-]+', '') 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '[34567].[56].[1]' AS val FROM dual
)

SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[0-9]+', 1, 1) AS A,  -- first occurrence
    REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[0-9]+', 1, 2) AS B,  -- second occurrence
    REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[0-9]+', 1, 3) AS C   -- third occurrence
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    val LIKE '[%].[%].[%]';
```

### Demo